# DAL - Error: Format of the initialization string does not confirm to specification starting at index 0

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2008

I am trying to improve my OOP language. I have three classes, Main class, dbClass and RecordHandleClass. I will get a error when btnInsert is executed in the main class. If I place call the code in same class or use static method then it will work. Presently I do not wish to implement static method so my question is...

1) how do I overcome this problem and

2) Where have I gone wrong.

Object is to insert some simple text in the database.

Thanks

Comment: On which line do you get this error?

Comment: @SonerGönül - I'm not getting error as such. When I execute the btninsert I get a error. I am not sure but I think Kev Hunter recommended a solution. So I will try that.

Comment: @SonerGönül - I have taken Kev Hunter recommendation I thought I have passed connection to RecordHandlerClass, cmdString. Please Correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is here

```
  CmdString = ("@INSERT INTO tblSimple (ID, FirstName, LastName) VALUES (@ID, @FirstName, @LastName)");
        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(CmdString))
```

You are initalizing a SqlConnection with your Insert string, you should be using your connection string here.

dbClass doesn't look like it would compile, but you could use that to return the SqlConnection you want properly initialized with the connection string

EDIT:

You dont really need to create the new SqlConnection you could just use the connection you have already created

Comment: I did experimented by not using the new SQLConnection and I am getting error "Error The name 'cnn' does not exist in the current context". If you don't mind what advice can you give. Are you saying I should try and call SQLConnection? I will try it after completing this comment

Comment: additional I thought I have passed the connection string, CmdString? Please correct me.

Comment: Nope, the CmdString is your insert statement, not your connection string

Comment: now I am asking myself how do I pass the connection string to the other class. I have modify the code but no insertion is implemented which does not reflect the table. I have made an update let me know what you think. I don't want to guess because I am trying to understand the architecture